# Spring AOP - @AfterThrowing doesn't working with method abstract class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing a Spring boot + Spring aop application deployed on Tomcat.

The problem I have is when there is an exception but *@AfterThrowing* is not working.

**LoggingAspect**

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect implements Ordered {

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * com.microservice.authorization..*(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void logAfterThrowingAllMethods(Exception ex) {
    log.error("****LoggingAspect.logAfterThrowingAllMethods() " + ex.getMessage());
}

@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return 100;
}
}
```

**BaseServiceImpl**

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<DTO, TRepository extends BaseRepository> {
   public abstract DTO mapperEntityResponse(Object obj) throws Exception;
}
```

**RoleServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<RoleDto, RoleRepository>**

```
@Service
public class RoleServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<RoleDto, RoleRepository> {
   @Autowired
   public RoleServiceImpl(RoleRepository repository_) {
    super(repository_);
   }

   @Override
   public RoleDto mapperEntityResponse(Object role) throws Exception {
     int a = 1/0;
     return RoleDto.builder().build();
   }
}
```

**Log**

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
> at com.microservice.authorization.service.impl.RoleServiceImpl.mapperEntityResponse(RoleServiceImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]

[image]

Comment: Please provide your AOP configuration, a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Sotirios
I am using default configuration of spring aop.

Comment: Yes, please write a [mre] that demonstrates the behavior you are seeing. And please provide a full stack trace.

Comment: Hi Sotirios
The problem I have is when there is an exception but @AfterThrowing is not working.
Example: https://github.com/minhtk1/spring-aop-demo

Comment: Yes, please take the relevant parts of the code and post them here as a [mre].  What do you mean by _default configuration of spring aop_?